# Displaying a view from an arbitrary method on iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiview

I'm pulling together a few utility methods for testing and I'd like to be able to pop up a view from within an arbitrary method - one that doesn't necessarily know about any UIViewControllers or windows. Is this possible?

For example I'm preparing a custom location manager shim so that I can manually inject location data when I'm testing. I'd like some of the methods to pop up a MKMapView to allow me to select the "current location" instead of manually entering lat/long values in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking @vodkhang's advice I took a peek at the code and created my own category (UIView+ShowThySelf) to pop up any arbitrary view from any method. For those interested it can be found on github

http://github.com/appsinyourpants/Pants-Framework

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is possible, even that I don't exactly know how to do it. The reason I know that this is possible because I see [FBConnect](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/) of Facebook and [DDSocialLoginDialog](http://github.com/digdog/DDSocialDialog) Library do what you are describing.

The source code and architecture of FBConnect is quite complex but DDSocialLoginDialog is easy to get and pull out the source code you need ( 2 classes with 4 files and few hundred lines of code) . Both are open source. Then, I hope that you can modify the source code so that it can add the MKMapView as a subview

Answer (score 1):

Summary of the previously mentioned methods, in case you want to roll your own code:

Create a UIControl.  Write a method to dismiss that control, and add it as a target to that control.  Place the view you want to pop up inside that control as a subview.  Use:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]
```

or (in the rare case your app has more than one window, such as VGA cable support):

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex: 0]
```

to find a place where to add a subview (the control you created).  Add it.